# How to get Mocha test name in the "before" hook?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to get the current `describe` name inside the `before` hook, like so:

```
describe('increasing 3 times', function() {

  before(function() {
    console.log('test name');
  });

  ...

});
```

I basically want to retrieve the 'increasing 3 times' string in the before hook.

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: In case mocha doesn't provide an API for that, you could store the name in a variable. It won't read as nicely though.

Comment: True.. I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's code that illustrates how you can do it:

```
describe("top", function () {
    before(function () {
        console.log("full title:", this.test.fullTitle());
        console.log("parent title:", this.test.parent.title);
    });

    it("test 1", function () {});
});
```

Run with the `spec` reporter, this will output:

```
full title: top "before all" hook
parent title: top
    ✓ test 1 


  1 passing (4ms)
```

When Mocha calls the functions you pass to its various functions (`describe`, `before`, `it`, etc.) the value of `this` is a `Context` object. One of the fields of this object is named `test`. It is a bit of a misnomer because it can point to something else than an actual test. In the case of a hook like `before` it points to the current `Hook` object created for the `before` call. Calling `fullTitle()` on this object will get you the hierarchical name of the object: the object's own name preceded by the name of the test suites (`describe`) that enclose it. A `Hook` object also has a `parent` field that points to the suite that contains the hook. And the suite has a `title` field which is the first argument that was passed to `describe`.